# How to get a memory map of a WSL process?

Tags: memory, process, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wonder is there any tools that can make a memory map/dump of a WSL process, I want to show that there's no PEBs but only native elf binarys. VMMAP doesn't work with WSL processes.

Comment: You don't need to get a memory map of a process to see there are only ELF binaries.  I suggest reviewing the official blogs starting with the architectural overview, which is really what you want for your proof. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/learn-about-windows-console-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/

Comment: @WSLUser I have already read these articles. I know exactly how WSL  works, but I want to show it in my PPT. I am preparing for a presentation of a OS course and showing how memory exactly is seems cooler.

Comment: You might be able to use the LeakSanitizer from ASAN to get the information you're looking for. Most issues regarding ASAN have been fixed (or worked-around): https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer You might find this 2016 Black Hat presentation useful as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p3RtkwstNk

Comment: @WSLUser I will check that, thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get the answer you need?